# How come some blocked sites still open after VPN is disabled?

Tags: networking, vpn

Let's say there is a website, and ISP is blocking it, or there is no tunnel(?) to the website. After enabling VPN, the site opens, VPN is disconnected, the site still opens - even in Private Sessions, even after cleaning network cache on that site.

I am curious to know what's the mechanism behind this?

Comment: Probably because they are only blocked by DNS. When you type `www.youtube.com` into the address bar your machine asks a "name server" what the actual address of a machine on the Internet is. If your problem is that your ISP name server is refusing to give you the address or your ISP is filtering name requests then your computer could "learn" the proper address while on a VPN and then it still works after disconnecting. There are lots of ways things are blocked and networking is complicated by machines caching various things.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, it seems that the ISP has blocked the site on its own
[DNS server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).

When you connected to the VPN, you have also avoided this DNS server
and used some other one as furnished by the VPN server.
While connected to the VPN, you have successfully resolved the
site-name to an IP address, and this was recorded on your computer
in a [DNS cache](https://www.keycdn.com/support/dns-cache),
which can be either that of your operating system or of your browser.

Later on, you have disconnected from the VPN, but the site's name was
still in the cache, so it was resolved locally against the cache and
without consulting the DNS server of the ISP. You were then able
to access it via the IP address that was found in the cache.

This success also means that the ISP has not blocked this site in its
firewall, but just in its DNS server. You might also in the future
be able to go around the ISP's DNS server, by using some other
DNS server, for example
[Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns).

Answer (score 0):

As @harrymc has told, probably the ISP has blocked the website only on its DNS Server. DNS Server is cached for some time. So you can access the site after VPN disconnects.

If this is true, then you don't need a VPN for accessing those sites. Just change your DNS server from Network Settings as required. Its easy to change DNS Server on all platforms including Windows, Linux as well as Android.